# 404 Error on Import Service

Tags: jss

I've set up a blank `Sitecore 9.1.1 XP` instance and tried to get `JSS` up and running.

I've installed the `Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.1.1 XP` package and 11.0.2 `sitecore-jss-cli`. I'm using the React sample app (https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/tree/dev/samples/react) and this is running correctly in disconnected mode.

The issue is when I try to deploy the react code to Sitecore using `jss deploy app -c -d`; I'm getting a 404 from the import service.

My layout service and API key are returning a JSON response as expected, so not sure where else to look.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've resolved this thanks to this blog, i had the import endpoint in my 
`scjssconfig.json` setup to http; setting this to https then gave me a certificate error. Setting my certificate to be trusted solved it as per the steps here:

https://www.codealamodeblog.com/Sitecore/JavaScript-Services/jss-troubleshooting-connecting-to-sitecore/